# Regex: How to handle empty quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, escaping

I have a String that has the following pattern:

```
"123 456 789 \"abc def\" \"ghi\" \"jkl\" \"mno\" \"pqr\" stu v 097 \"wx yz\""
```

I want to split this string in a way that the elements outside quotes are split using " " and the ones inside quotes are split using quotes. The regular expression that I am using for this purpose is :

```
"(['\"])((?:\\\\\\1|.)+?)\\1|([^\\s\"']+)"
```

The output generated is:

```
123, 456, 789, "abc def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", stu, v, 097, "wx yz"
```

This output is fine but the problem is that if I have an empty quote, the regular expression messes up the output. For example, let's remove pqr from the above input string.

```
"123 456 789 \"abc def\" \"ghi\" \"jkl\" \"mno\" \"\" stu v 097 \"wx yz\""
```

The output in this case is :

```
123, 456, 789, "abc def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "" stu v 097 ", wx, yz
```

The main problem is the `"" stu v 097 "`. The desired output was :

```
123, 456, 789, "abc def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "", stu, v, 097, "wx yz"
```

How can I handle the empty string by modifying the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex seems to work for me:

```
(?:(['"]).*?\1)|(?:[^\s"']+)
```

As a Java string, it's:

```
"(?:(['\"]).*?\\1)|(?:[^\\s\"']+)"
```

You can see what it matches [here](http://fiddle.re/w4c5t6), just click Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is right. For get desired output just replace `+` on `*`:

```
(['"])((?:\\\1|.)*?)\1|([^\s"']+)
```

Note, that `+` means *one or more times*. But you can get empty quotes like "". So we need *zero or more* times - `*`

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday when i was contemplating on your problem. I came up with this. This seems to be the other way around. Or may be not!

```
((\"[\w\s]*\")|(\d+|\w+))
```

As a java String.

```
((\"[\\w\\s]*\")|(\\d+|\\w+))
```